# Find the best combination with lower cost

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a array like this:

```
fee=[1 => 10,2=>18,4=>32,8=>60]
```

I want to get the result like:

```
7 -> 4+2+1 => 32+18+10
7=>60

9  -> 8+1 => 60+10
9=>70
```

Here 7, 9 are input value

How it solve this problem?

Comment: show a **payment ** 1,2,4,8 are hours and 10,18,32,60 are currency ($)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but this looks like [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) domain. This is not really a trivial task.

Comment: to me it seems pure binary operations, the index are powers of 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through the groups of the fee and get the integer value of the count which is possible. Save the value and proceed until all groups are checked.

The array, which is iterated has to be sorted by lowest cost first, then higher cost and by greater package first.

```js
function getLowestCost(value, fee) {
    var result = { cost: 0 };

    result.rest = Object.keys(fee).sort(function (a, b) {
        return fee[a] / a - fee[b] / b || b - a;
    }).reduce(function (r, a) {
        result[a] = Math.floor(r / a);
        result.cost += result[a] * fee[a];
        return r % a;
    }, value);

    return result;
}

console.log(getLowestCost(7, { 1: 10, 2: 18, 4: 32, 8: 60 }));
console.log(getLowestCost(9, { 1: 10, 2: 18, 4: 32, 8: 60 }));

console.log(getLowestCost(7, { 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 32, 8: 60 }));
console.log(getLowestCost(9, { 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 32, 8: 60 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: fee is array not object

Comment: really? i see an object.

Comment: @Mahi, `fee` is a PHP associative array, which is an equivalent of a javascript object.

Comment: @NinaScholz, really great algorithm, though it might fail with costs like `{ 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 32, 8: 60 }`.

Comment: @sevavietl, it should work now with priority of greater packages.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit tricky but this works and is scaleble:

```
var arr = [10, 18, 32, 60];
var search = 7;
var result = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < (search >>> 0).toString(2).length; i++) {
    if ((search >>> 0).toString(2)[i] == "1") {
        result += arr[i];
    }
}
// result = 60
```

Explanation: The `(search >>> 0).toString(2)` converts the seached value (7) to a binary mask. `7 => 111` and `9 => 1001`. Then it loops through the each char of this binary string and checks if it's a 0 or 1 and adds the equivalent from the array to the result.